# Macro in C to replace a 0 with 1

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have a couple of defines in my program that give a size to an array. Now, you can't initialise an array with size 0. So I need a way to check this value and if it's a zero, put 1. I've never used any macro's before, but this is what I came up with:

```
#define MINIMUMONE(i)  do{if(i == 0){return 1;}else{return i;}}while(0)
```

and then initialising my arrays like so:

```
int directIn[MINIMUMONE(NRDIRECTINPUTS)] = {0};
```

with `NRDIRECTINPUTS` defined in a separate file. Now I'm getting the error *expected primary expression before 'do'*, *expected '`' before 'do'* and *expected '}' at the end of input*. Since I've never used macro's before, I'm first of all not even sure this is possible.

Now, whilst typing this question I came to the revelation that that's totally not how macro's work, but they simply replace the he define with what comes after it. Is there a way to do what I desire? I'm using Arduino, so it's C/C++, in case this might be helpful.

Comment: C or C++? It results different answers as C99 supports variable length array so `MININUMONE` can return a variable instead of a constant, while C++03 does not support it.

Comment: May I suggest using `std::array<T, N>` over `T[N]`? They allow a size of 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define MINIMUMONE(i) ( (i) ? (i) : 1 )`

Comment: I would even do `(i) || 1`, to avoid side-effects if there are any, with the realization that you have to evaluate `i` at least once, so any side effect happens exactly once.

Comment: @NitzanShaked: Problem, `(i) || 1` always returns `1`, even if `i` was `2`.

Comment: Both good points (although Nitzan's solution isn't value preserving, while Ben's is). I corrected, @BenVoigt.

Comment: @BenVoigt: duh. I was thinking Python/node. My bad.

Answer (score 6):

Why use a macro when you can use `constexpr`-functions?

```
constexpr std::size_t minimumone( std::size_t i )
{
    return i == 0? 1 : i;
}
```

---

For the sake of the commentators, here is a branchless version of the above code:

```
constexpr std::size_t minimumone( std::size_t i )
{
    return i + (i == 0); // Becomes at least 1 whatever value i has.
}
```

And of course a template version:

```
template< std::size_t N >
constexpr std::size_t minimumone()
{
    return N == 0? 1 : N;
}
```

And since C++1y, it gets even better:

```
template< std::size_t N >
std::size_t minimumone = (N == 0? 1 : N);
```

Comment: Good choice, but I'd suggest avoiding the conditional.

Comment: Conditionals are absolutely irrelevant at compile time!

Comment: Sad that `std::max` is not `constexpr`.

Comment: I must say I have never heard about these functions. Since I've only had class about C and not C++, I think I'll keep safe and use the macro (also since I'm sure this is at compile time). I'll keep this in mind though and look up exactly what they are, thanks.

Comment: It works perfect! `constexpr`-functions are simply functions which you can use in constant expressions such as bounds for an array. They were created for this purpose, and they fit in here perfectly. Don't use macros, you're ignoring a very useful feature here.

Comment: @Arcoth " obviously it is never gonna be used at runtime": You are probably right here, but it's hard to guarantee. Next thing you know somebody else is using it in the inner loop of a pixel shader.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version with no conditional:

```
#define MINIMUMONE(i) ((i) + !(i))
```